# Strange data-attribute boolean issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a live -on click- event for a Header which has an arrow flipping up/down upon opening & closing it's contents.

The strangest thing is happening with `!` followed by a variable -- which is supposed to flip it from true -> false, and vice versa.  Basically it's not working at all, and it flips to false and stays there... Check out the fiddle to see what I mean.

I've deleted lots of code for the sake of brevity.

[Demo Code](http://jsfiddle.net/JKUJb/1/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.regimenHeader', function () {
    var _state = $(this).attr('data-state');

    if (_state === 'true') {
        // do stuff
    }

    else { 
        // do stuff
    }

    // This is where the issue is happening, it isn't flipping the Boolean value
    // !"true" = false, !true = false, it works with strings or booleans
    $(this).attr('data-state', !_state);
});​
```

I can get it working perfectly fine if I do the following:

```
    if (_state === 'true') {
        // Manually flip the data-state boolean
        $(this).attr('data-state', false);
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing why this isn't working the way it should ?? Just wondering why it's doing this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JKUJb/2/

if so, the problem was that you are using `.attr()` which returns a string, so if you convert:

```
!"true" //false

!"false" //false
```

`.data()` on the other hand returns the value already "casted

**EDIT:**

Just to be more clear, in javascript the only falsy values are:

```
false;
null;
undefined;
'';
0;
NaN;
```

So if you really wanted to use `.attr()`, you could, but I recommend that first you do:

```
var _state = $(this).attr('data-state') === 'true'; //if 'true' then true, false otherwise
```

Good luck!

Comment: Next time i'll stick to `.data()` haha. I simply wanted it to be visible in `[data-state]` so I could search for all of them as opposed to looping through all headers and then seeing if they have `.data('state') === true etc. Appreciate the help though!

Comment: Glad I helped, if you're having some information in an element, `.data()` it's probably what you're looking for :). Just in case you want to see some performance test: http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr/22

Answer (score 2):

Change your second line to:

```
var _state = $(this).attr('data-state') == 'true';
```

And in the if statement check for boolean:

```
if ( _state ) {
 // do stuff
 ...
```

Comment: Boom there it is... I just needed to turn it into a Boolean, thanks Vlad. Works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/JKUJb/4/

Answer (score 1):

_state is a String (typeof _state === String //true) you need to convert it to a boolean first
(a String will alwase be true)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `data-` attributes for this, use jQuery's `.data` method to retrieve and set the value. It will automatically convert the string "true" into a Boolean, or the string "1" into a number:

```
$(document).on('click', '.regimenHeader', function () {
    var _state = $(this).data('state');
    if (_state) {
        // do something
    }
    $(this).data('state', !_state);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JKUJb/6/

Or you could toggle a class -- you can use the `.hasClass` method to return a Boolean:

```
$(document).on('click', '.regimenHeader', function () {
    var _state = $(this).hasClass('data-state');
    if (_state) {
        // do something
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('data-state');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JKUJb/3/

Comment: I thought about doing it, at this point just wanted to figure out why `data-` was acting so strange, but I see now, it keeps coming back as a string and i'm not testing it here: `var _state = $(this).attr('data-state') === 'true'`